# back button in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there is a way to hide back button for android devices and make it visible for iOS devices?

Following code displays **Back** button for both devices.

```
const Stack =  createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen : LoginTabs,
    navigationOptions : {
      header: null  
    }
    },
  Home : {
    screen : Home,
    navigationOptions : {
      title : 'Dashboard',
      headerStyle : {
        backgroundColor : '#1565C0'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you can do

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state } = navigation
if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
    return {
      title: 'title',
      headerLeft: (
          <Button />
      ),
    }
}else{
return {
      title: 'title',
      headerLeft: (
        null
      ),
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: glad to help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can import Platform from react-native like:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
```

And check in your component like:

```
if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
//Render Back button
}
```